# MySQL full text search not working on some words

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have made a MySQL full text search with min search length of 3 characters, search is working fine except for some words no results are return where result are available.

If i search for word `avg` results are returned., If i search for word `how` no result are returned.

I am trying this way.

```
$keyword = preg_replace('/  */', ' *', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' *', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\W+/', ' *', $keyword);
$keyword = "$keyword*";

$query = "SELECT *, MATCH (title, link) AGAINST ( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rel FROM $table WHERE MATCH (title, link) AGAINST ( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP by rel DESC, $order $sort LIMIT $rpp OFFSET $offset";
```

I tried these solution too but same no result for word `how'

```
//Changing
$keyword = preg_replace('/  */', ' +', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' +', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\W+/', ' +', $keyword);

$keyword = preg_replace('/  */', '+', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $keyword);
$keyword = preg_replace('/\W+/', '+', $keyword);

//In combination
$keyword = "+$keyword*";
$keyword = "$keyword*";    
$keyword = "+$keyword";
$keyword = "$keyword";
```

Please see and suggest why my search is not working on some words.

Thanks.

**Update**
The word `how` is present in 10 rows,
The word `avg` is present in 16 rows.
I have more than 650 rows. 
I am using `IN BOOLEN MODE` in query too so there should be not problem about MySQL 50% rule to make `how` a stop word .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`avg` and `how` are both too short in standard configuration, see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). You changed that, but `how` is an element of the [stop word list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) :

> Boolean full-text searches have these characteristics:
>
> The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply.
>
> The stopword list applies.

Override the stopword list with the `ft_stopword_file` system variable:

> To override the default stopword list, set the ft_stopword_file system
>   variable. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The variable
>   value should be the path name of the file containing the stopword
>   list, or the empty string to disable stopword filtering.

Comment: Yes I just found out it and did that, I will accept you answer as it will guide anyone looking for same solution.